# Response signal of killing a process in linux with 'kill' command

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kill-process

Is there a way to get a callback/signal after killing a linux process with kill/pkill command?

Comment: Who/what needs to receive the callback/signal?

Comment: Same process, which called 'kill' to take further action.

Comment: But what is this "process"? Is it a c program? A shell script? What? A C program can use [`waitpid`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) to wait for the process to exit.

Comment: It's a shell script.

Comment: No. You can use `wait $pid` - it will return when the process with $pid is terminated. Or some sort of mechanism using available commands _(pgrep)_ to make sure that the process is killed and you can continue further.

Comment: As much I know, `wait $pid` only waits for child processes. I'm killing a process with a specific PID, which was started from some other program. and then trying to get something to be sure that killing of process(PID) has been successful.